Try to set false value using UseQuery Vue
I am learning Vue at the moment. I'm trying to create a loader from the front-end for a table. I set the value true first before getting results from the endpoint so that the loader can work in <tableRow>. After successfully getting data from the endpoint I have to set the loader value to false.
  const dataLoader = ref<any>(false); //set default dataLoader here

  const {
    data: listCourse,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["...", listQuery],
    queryFn: async () => {
      dataLoader.value = true;
      const result = await useBackendApi<PaginationResult<Course>>(
        "[endpoint]",
        {
          method: "GET",
          params: listQuery,
        },
      );

      return result;
    },
    placeholderData: {} as PaginationResult<Course>,
  });

Then I was confused about where I can set the value false because onSettled/onSuccess/onError cannot be added after the placeholder and just return:
No overload matches this call.
Can anyone help me?
